# parsing xml in bash with XMLStarlet and saving the result in ${channel} format

Tags: xml, linux, bash, rss

so, i'm going to write a rss **scraper** in bash using xmlstarlet as its xml parser and wget as its rss downloader (i done the wget part, so no question on it), but i got a question on parsing each item in a feed with it and save it with the format: ${channel}, etc (i had done storing it in echo -e format (i mean, displaying it as stdout), now i'd like to parse each item in a feed with XMLStarlet and save it with the format: ${channel}, etc), in short, i'm going to do something similar to this in C#:

```
//ignore the classes, they're just illustrations    
public class RSSClass
    {
        public string Title { get; set; } //definition
        public string PubDate { get; set; }
    }
    
    
    void myRSS_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{

        var rssData = from rss in XElement.Parse(e.Result).Descendants("item")
           

         select new RSSClass
                    {
                        Title = rss.Element("title").Value,   //this stores the value in <title/> in the respective string named Title
                        PubDate = rss.Element("pubDate").Value  //this is also done the same thing 
                    };
```

}

and i don't know how to do the same thing in bash as just got no idea what bash is (i'm really new in bash)

UPDATE: i wrote some sort of sekeleton code in bash (though i still didn't figure out the bash xml parsing thingy):

```
#!/bin/bash

RSS_URI="http://rss.detik.com/index.php/hot"
XPATH_MATCH=/rss/channel/item
XPATH_VALUE="concat(pubDate,' | ',title,'\n')"
RSS_DATA="data.xml"
${channel}
${pubdate}
${title}
${link}

DOWNLOAD_AND_PARSE ()   #Downloads and parses RSS [SKELETON]
{
    wget -O RSS_DATA RSS_URI
    echo -e "$(~/bin/xml sel --net -t -m "$XPATH_MATCH" -v "$XPATH_VALUE" "$RSS_DATA")" | awk -F "|" '{print $1 $2}'   
}
```

and i don't know what to do to after :|

thanks in advance for your solution/answers/etc

EDIT: i just recently found out how to separate outputs off, now the question on how do i store it in ${} format is still a question

Comment: Perhaps someone will understand what you're asking, but I don't. Why don't you try to provide specific actual examples of what the input is and what you want it to turn into.

Comment: well, this question is sort of hard to explain, plus, my english is not so good... *i personally don't know what to write here since it's pretty hard to explain the problem*

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words. If you can't draw a picture, *just give an example*